# Tweening Text; how to rotate text around a chart

Tags: d3.js

I use a simple definition of an arc like this:

```
// definition of how an arc looks like
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(20)
    .outerRadius(30)
    .startAngle(function(d){return d.mystartangle;})
    .endAngle(function(d){return d.myendangle;});
```

in combination with a tweening/ transition definition like this:

```
// definition of how to nicely tween an arc
function arcTween(newdata, index) {
    var i1 = d3.interpolate(olddata.mystartangle, newdata.mystartangle);
    var i1 = d3.interpolate(olddata.myendangle, newdata.myendangle);
    return function(t) {
        newdata.mystartangle = i1(t);
        newdata.myendangle = i2(t);
        return arc(newdata);
    };
};
```

to very nicely update a donut chart, which is made of individual arcs. The result looks as smooth as in here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636 but with bound data.

```
// arcs
// ... ENTER
vizBody.selectAll('path.arcs')
    .data(mydata)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'arcs')
        .attr('d', arc);
// ... UPDATE
vizBody.selectAll('path.arcs')
    .data(mydata)
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attrTween('d', arcTween);
```

Now I need to label the arcs with texts to finish my diagram. **I want to tween / transition these text-labels the same way as the arcs**. I couldn't find a tutorial with bound data and nice text transitions. Thus I though to use the same idea as with the arcs, but I already fail at this point:

```
var mytext = d3.svg.text()
```

Obviously there is no d3.svg.text(). Google shows only 2 hits with this code-snippet in parentheses.

Why is this not working in d3?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I think this situation is slightly different because OP wants to transition/tween the text content itself, while also transitioning/tweening the arc. This can be easily done, but requires a different technique than that given in the answer to the question you linked as a duplicate. [HERE](http://jsbin.com/hoxuy/1/edit?js,output) is a link to the solution for the OP of this question. Can we reopen so I can post it as an answer with an explanation?

Comment: @jshanley My reading of the question was that the problem was the tweening of the position. Happy to reopen though if OP disagrees. Nice example BTW.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yes, please open this question again. It is not about how to tween text like in the linked answer. My question is, why 'var mytext = d3.svg.text()' doesn't work, whereas all other svg-elements work like 'var arc = d3.svg.arc()'

Comment: @Steevie Ok, reopened. I'm not sure if I understand your question though -- as you point out yourself, there is no `d3.svg.text()`, so I'm not sure how you would want it to "work".

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks so much. Because I am quite new to d3 I might have missed some basics. I know that I can create variables of svg elements by `var myarc=d3.svg.arc()` or `var myline=d3.svg.line()`. Therefore I don't understand why `var mytext=d3.svg.text()` does not work. I think I am not seeing the wood for the trees.

Comment: Well what do you want to do, or expect to happen? Is @jshanley's solution what you're looking for?

Comment: There is no svg `arc` element. The functions that d3 gives you under the namespace `d3.svg` are used to generate data for `<path>` elements or groups of several different elements as in `d3.svg.axis()`. For creating elements, you can simply `.append()` the element to a selection. For instance, `var myText = 'this is some text';` followed by `svg.append('text').text(myText)` would create an svg `<text>` element containing the text `'this is some text'`

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I expected an explanation and jshanley just gave it; my code is not working because 'arc' and 'line' are d3 functions ontop of svg whereas 'text' has no representation in the d3 namespace. I will now go with the solution of jshanley. Thanks for the discussion.